# NSURLSession background download sometimes delayed

Tags: ios, background, geolocation, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I've an app that is already background-enabled. It should send two http-request whenever a geofence is entered or exited.

I'm using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` (since UploadTask has no didFinish-delegate) and I have set the temporary download folder permission to `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`. My `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` is set to 1. The session is created with backgroundSessionConfiguration and I have only one Identifier.

Sometimes it is working perfectly but sometimes iOS is delaying the request up to the next time I unlock my screen / start the app. If that happens it is then sequentially (due to my maximum connections = 1) sending all delayed request at once.

Do I miss something? Is there a way to tell iOS something like "this request is critical in time, don't delay it"?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the session with a background session configuration, you're probably getting bitten by the discretionary flag being set automatically for requests that begin while the app is in the background.  Unless there's a really good reason to use a background session for this, that's probably a mistake in this case.